# Discontinous Function maximum on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

When I have a discontinous $f$ on a compact set $K$, does it have a maximum when I assume that $\underset{x \in K}{\sup}f(x) < \infty $.

Answer (score 2):

It does not. Consider $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - 1/n & \text{if } x = 1/n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ It is clear that $f$ is bounded with $\sup_{x \in K} f(x) = 1$, but it never actually attains a maximum. The issue is that while $f([0,1])$ is bounded it is not closed, so it does not necessarily attain its supremum.